# Obtain SSRS URL from MS CRM 2011 plugin context

Tags: c#, reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2011

Is it possible to obtain SSRS URL used as back-end on given MS CRM server?

The issue is that reporting services could be installed on different URLs depending on SQL server configuration, and I want my CRM plugin be able to work on every database without further configuration or re-compilation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the only supported way is to use [Deployment Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xrm.sdk.deployment.retrieverequest.aspx). Other workaround (of course I know that this is bad) to use direct SQL Query to read info from mscrm_config db.